# If statements not working properly discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a discord bot, with a swear word filter, and I made a command to add and remove words. The remove function is working, but the add fails at the moment you type c!setconf swearWords add with no args, it is supposed to send an error message, which it does in the remove one, but in the add one, it sends "Word undefined has been already added"

I've looked up the code, and its the exact one in the 2 cases, so I don't really know what is the mistake.

```js
    if(args[0] === "swearWords") {
      if(!args[1]) return message.channel.send(
      new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setDescription(`Add banned words by typing \`${client.guildConf.prefix}csetconf swearWords add <word>\` and remove one by typing \`${client.guildConf.prefix}csetconf swearWords remove <word>\``)
      .setColor(vars.good)
      )
      if(args[1] === "add") {
        if(client.configs.get(message.guild.id, args[2], "swearWords")) {
          message.channel.send(
            new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setDescription(`Word \`${args[2]}\` has been already added!`)
            .setColor(vars.error)
          )
          return;
        } else if(!args[2]) {
          message.channel.send(
            new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setDescription(`Specify a valid word to add!`)
            .setColor(vars.error)
          )
        } else {
        client.configs.push(message.guild.id, args[2], "swearWords")
        message.channel.send(
          new Discord.RichEmbed()
          .setDescription(`Banned word \`${args[2]}\` added`)
          .setColor(vars.good)
        )
        }
      } else if(args[1] === "remove") {
        if(!client.configs.get(message.guild.id, args[2], "swearWords")) {
          message.channel.send(
            new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setDescription(`Word \`${args[2]}\` is not a banned word here!`)
            .setColor(vars.error)
          )
          return;
        } else if(!args[2]) {
          message.channel.send(
            new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setDescription(`Specify a valid word to remove!`)
            .setColor(vars.error)
          )
        } else {
        client.configs.remove(message.guild.id, args[2], "swearWords")
        message.channel.send(
          new Discord.RichEmbed()
          .setDescription(`Banned word \`${args[2]}\` removed`)
          .setColor(vars.error)
        )
        }
      } else {
        message.channel.send(
          new Discord.RichEmbed()
          .setDescription(`Invalid action! Use \`add\` or \`remove\` instead.`)
          .setColor(vars.error)
        )
      }
    }
```

Sorry 'bout all that code, but its necessary
Also, no error console log output.
The expected result is to make c!setconf swearWords add to reply with the else if(!args[2] thing, the remove option is working perfectly but the add one fails with that.
Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand of your problem, you want to make sure that the value is not undefined when you are adding a word. From the looks, you are checking if `args[2]` is `undefined` with `!args[2]` after another statement, which seems as if it is returning `true`. I would suggest swapping these around.

```
...
if(args[1] === "add") {
    //Check that args[2] isn't undefined first
    if(!args[2]) {
        message.channel.send(
            new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setDescription(`Specify a valid word to add!`)
                .setColor(vars.error)
            )
    } else if(client.configs.get(message.guild.id, args[2], "swearWords")) {
        message.channel.send(
            new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setDescription(`Word \`${args[2]}\` has been already added!`)
                .setColor(vars.error)
        )
        return;
    } else {
        client.configs.push(message.guild.id, args[2], "swearWords")
        message.channel.send(
          new Discord.RichEmbed()
              .setDescription(`Banned word \`${args[2]}\` added`)
              .setColor(vars.good)
        )
    }
}
...
```